# Using a 2d array for user and passwords

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays, multidimensional-array

Basically I have a text file formatted like this

```
user, pass
username, password
```

etc.

I'm wanting to store these to an array, where I can then check my text boxes against the array.
Would my best bet to use a 2d array?

I'm unsure how to split these for a 2d array at the comma and then at the line, and if I did so would the outcome be (using the examples from above)

```
array[0][0] = user
array[0][1] = pass
array [1][0]= username 
array [1][1]= password
```

I don't fully understand 2d arrays, but feel it would be the best way of dealing with this problem. So how would I go about splitting these?

I also thought I could just use a normal array, then do something like this

```
textboxUser.Text+", "+textboxPass.Text
```

and compare that to each string in the array but feel this would be bad practice.

PS: This is for learning, im well aware not to save passwords as plain text, but that is not important this will not be used as an actual site.
Thanks!

Also If there are better ways please let me know.

Comment: What's the relationship/difference between "user" and "username", and "pass" and "password"? (Beyond that, I'd just as soon roll a basic plain class to contain the information rather than dealing with arrays)

Comment: Please DON'T! This is not PHP. Write a class called `User` with properties called `Username` and `Password`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data construct you choose, depends on what you exactly want to do with it further on. You could use two dimensional array, but you could also go object oriented and construct a class called Credentials, which encompasses user and password information. Something like this:

```
class Credentials
{
  public string User { get; set; }
  public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

And have a list or array of Credentials objects.

Comment: Thanks a lot, dont know why I didnt think of this initially. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Why not use hashmap for key value pairs